# To compute the variance of a dataset, is N or N-1 needed?

Tags: probability, statistics

This [video](https://youtu.be/-S_d-kI2IHo?t=132) is using N instead of N-1 to compute the variance of a dataset.

In statistics, [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) is the use of n − 1 instead of n in the formula for the sample variance and sample standard deviation, where n is the number of observations in a sample.

The key is,

is this dataset a sample or a population?

Comment: The key is, what do you want? Your dataset's own variance, or the best estimate of the variance of the population it was drawn from? The latter isn't even a variance, it's an estimate.

Comment: If the dataset represents a random _sample_ from a much larger poulation, then $n-1$ is used to estimate the population variance. However If the dataset represents the _full_ population, then $n$ is correct.

Comment: It seems that both commenters above agree with your final sentence (as do I). The key is indeed whether this is a sample or a population.

Comment: I think (maybe I am wrong, I am not a statisticus) that $n$ is used by populations only because $\frac{n}{n-1}$ is so small ($n$ is large) that it can be ignored. There is IMV nothing wrong with taking $n-1$ there also and actually it is more precise. If there is a "population of $n=1$" (contradictio in terminis) then it is not even possible to discern something like variance. That is confirmed by the use of $n-1$ (not allowed to be $0$) but not by the use of $n$.

Comment: In the video, there's no indication that the data represents a random sample from a much larger population, hence in the context of the video, I would assume the datasets represent full populations. After all, if that data is sample data, those are ridiculously small samples, and wouldn't make sense for reliable estimates of the population variances.

Comment: @drhab On the other hand, if the population is $1$, and you sample from that population, you expect no variation in the samples, so variance $0$ makes sense. The issue of $n$ versus $n-1$ is basically whether what you have is what you are sampling from and you want a measure on how spread out samples are expected to be, or what you have is a set of samples and you want to use that to estimate how spread out you can expect other samples to be. In the latter case, a set of $1$ makes the question nonsensical, but not the former.

Comment: @RosieF Its own variance of the dataset.

Comment: For its own variance, $n$ is correct.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I see that what I said in my former comment should be modified. I should have spoken of a "sample containing $n=1$ observation". That observation on its own does not say anything about the variance of the underlying random variable (corresponding with $n-1=0$).

Comment: If the data is known to be a random sample from a much larger population, then computing the dataset's own variance is not very meaningful since presumably the goal is to estimate the population variance. Thus in that case, it's standard to divide by $n-1$ to avoid a bias in the estimate.

Comment: If you know the mean in advance, divide by $n$.  If you use the sample average to estimate the mean, divide by $n-1$.